# mysql on custom folder

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, directory

I have already installed MySQL 5.7 (using apt-get) on an Ubuntu server but  I need to install version 5.5. I have used the tar.gz binary package and installed it under `/home/mysql55/mysql`. Now I need to start it and it's driving me crazy because it somehow tries to access `/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys` and it can't. So it seems it gets confused by the existing 5.7 version installed and search to the default installation paths, even though on the *mysqld* command line I execute the following command:

```
./mysqld --basedir=/home/mysql55/mysql --datadir=/home/mysql55/mysql/data --pid-file=/home/mysql55/mysql/host.pid --socket=/home/mysql55/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3307
```

The error I see is:

```
[ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
```

I have not tried to use `mysqld_safe` because it also makes the assumption that all is installed under `/usr/local`.

Please advise.